# Rspec test expecting memory values to be the same?

Tags: ruby, rspec, tdd

I have this Rspec test that is failing and i'm not understanding how to solve it.

it seems like the error is because they are differents instances of the object, so they got differents memory values.

How can i maintain a memory value object when create a object that will behaviour in the same way if given the same input?

```
describe '#==' do
let(:cpf) {described_class.new('01201201202')}

it 'verifies the key equality' do
    expect(cpf).to eq described_class.new('01201201202')
```

Error:

```
 1) PixKey#== verifies the key equality
 Failure/Error: expect(cpf).to eq described_class.new('01201201202')

   expected: #<PixKey:0x0000018d191b8670 @value="01201201202", @key="01201201202", @type="cpf">
        got: #<PixKey:0x0000018d191b8b70 @value="01201201202", @key="01201201202", @type="cpf">

   (compared using ==)

   Diff:
   @@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
   -#<PixKey:0x0000018d191b8670
   +#<PixKey:0x0000018d191b8b70
     @key="01201201202",
     @type="cpf",
     @value="01201201202">
```

Any ideas would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behavior of the `==` method returns `true` when both objects refer to the same hash key. Because in your example both elements are different instances their hash value would be different.

If you want two instances of `PixKey` to be considered equal if they have the same `@value` and/or `@key` then you need to override the default implementation with your own implementation, for example like this:

```
# in your `PixKey` class
def ==(other)
  self.class == other.class && @key == other.key && @value == other.value
end
```

Comment: I'm kind of new to Ruby and always got amazed by the flexibility of this language. This worked as intended. Thanks for you help!

Comment: A very minor point, re: `==` being based on "the same hash key", the docs say, instead: "At the Object level, #== returns true only if obj and other
are the same object.". I interpret this to mean that `Object#==` is based on memory address, not a hashing function. Again, this is a very minor point, which beginners should feel free to ignore.